# Pass fieldsToNull in SOAP for custom web service

Tags: apex, soap-api, soap

I have written a custom web service which has a date coming in from different environment. Date can be null. lets call the tag as `dateTag` which gets map to some date field on my object in CRM. When I pass null or blank field in this tag, i get below error

> '' is not a valid value for the type
>   xsd:date

After some research, I came to know that I have to use `<fieldtonull>` but having a hard time to figure out where to put it in SOAP and how to use it in code when consuming a custom web service. Another question I have is, can `<fieldtonull>` be used in case of custom webservice??

**Thanks in advance**